# Pass the URL Dynamically Stored in custom Field to LWC Navigation(standard__webpage)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightningnavigation, navigationmixin.navigate

**Scenario:** I have a Custom Field (dataType: URL) on a Custom Object. I need to Pass this Value to the Navigation(standard__webpage) LWC Service Dynamically. In the code given below "Per__c.Id_File__c" is the custom field that stores the URL(which is different for every record)

**JS Code:**

```
import { api, LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import FILE_URL from '@salesforce/schema/Per__c.Identification_File__c';

const FIELDS = [
    'Per__c.Name',
    'Per__c.Id_File__c'
]
export default class Files extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord,{recordId: '$recordId',fields: FIELDS})Per__c;

    get name()
    {
        return this.Per__c.data.fields.Name.value;
    }

    get fileURL()
    {
      this.Per__c.data.fields.Id_File__c.value; 
    }

   filePreview() {
       console.log('Naviation Invoked');
       console.log('URl Lodded'+FILE_URL);
       this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: 'https://www.google.ca' // pass the url Dynamically
            
        }
    },
    false
  );
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Id Record" icon-name="utility:file">
<template if:true={Per__c.data}>
    <p>{name}</p>
    <lightning-button label="View File" variant="brand" value="file preview" onclick={filePreview}></lightning-button>
</template>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the URL stored in your field to the url attribute of the Navigate method:

```
...
   get fileURL()
    {
      return this.Per__c.data.fields.Id_File__c.value; 
    }

   filePreview() {
       console.log('Naviation Invoked');
       console.log('URl Lodded'+FILE_URL);
       this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: this.fileURL() // pass the url Dynamically
            
        }
    },
...
```

See the documentation for reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_page_types